# Prolog Family Relation, unexpected failure

Tags: prolog, program-slicing

Could anyone tell me why my aunt relation isn't working? It just returns false whenever I try to call it.

The Uncle relation I wrote under it seems to work perfectly. I can't figure out what the difference is. I tried (not(mother(X,Y)). at the end also but that doesn't change anything.

```
/* FACTS */
parents(david, george, noreen).
parents(jennifer, george, noreen).
parents(georgejr, george, noreen).
parents(scott, george, noreen).
parents(joanne, george, noreen).
parents(jessica, david, edel).
parents(clara, david, edel).
parents(michael, david, edel).
parents(laura, georgejr, susan).
parents(anna, scott, siobhan).


/* Relationships */
father(X, Y) :- parents(Y, X, _).
male(X) :- father(X, _).

mother(X, Y) :- parents(Y, _, X).
female(X) :- mother(X, _).

grandfather(X, Y) :- father(X, Z), father(Z, Y).
grandfather(X, Y) :- father(X, Z), mother(Z, Y).

grandmother(X, Y) :- mother(X, Z), mother(Z, Y).
grandmother(X, Y) :- mother(X, Z), father(Z, Y).

brother(X, Y) :- male(X), father(Z, X), father(Z, Y).

sister(X, Y) :- female(X), father(Z, X), father(Z, Y).

aunt(X,Y) :- sister(X,Z), parents(Y, Z, _).
aunt(X,Y) :- sister(X,Z), parents(Y, _, Z).

uncle(X, Y) :- brother(X, Z), parents(Y, Z, _), not(father(X,Y)).
uncle(X, Y) :- brother(X, Z), parents(Y, _, Z), not(father(X,Y)).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are introducing a lot of redundancy and at least strange checking mechanisms.

The `father` and `mother` relationship imply that you specify the `parents/3` relationship as `parents(child,father,morther)`. I don't see why you define two queries.

What goes wrong is that the brother and sister relationship will succeed on `brother(X,X)`. One can avoid this with `X \= X`, this is basically what you resolve in the aunt clause.

Furthermore you will need to provide additional information. The `male` and `female` relationship are only resolved when the person (`X`) has children. It is however possible to be an aunt or uncle when you have no children on your own.

This should work:

```
/* FACTS */

parents(david, george, noreen).
parents(jennifer, george, noreen).
parents(georgejr, george, noreen).
parents(scott, george, noreen).
parents(joanne, george, noreen).
parents(jessica, david, edel).
parents(clara, david, edel).
parents(michael, david, edel).
parents(laura, georgejr, susan).
parents(anna, scott, siobhan).


/* Relationships */

parent(X,Y) :- parents(Y,X,_).
parent(X,Y) :- parents(Y,_,X).

father(X, Y) :- parents(Y, X, _).

male(michael).
male(X) :- father(X, _).

mother(X, Y) :- parents(Y, _, X).

female(joanne).
female(jessica).
female(jennifer).
female(clara).
female(laura).
female(anna).
female(X) :- mother(X, _).

grandfather(X, Y) :- father(X, Z), father(Z, Y).
grandfather(X, Y) :- father(X, Z), mother(Z, Y).

grandmother(X, Y) :- mother(X, Z), mother(Z, Y).
grandmother(X, Y) :- mother(X, Z), father(Z, Y).

brother(X, Y) :- male(X), father(Z, X), father(Z, Y), X \= Y.

sister(X, Y) :- female(X), father(Z, X), father(Z, Y), X \= Y.

aunt(X,Y) :- sister(X,Z), parent(Z,Y).

uncle(X, Y) :- brother(X, Z), parent(Z,Y).
```

Comment: I got all of the above code from my lecturer bar the aunt / uncle relation. Could you tell me exactly what I need to change? I'm very very new to prolog and quite lost.

Comment: A minute please, I'm running some tests (no offense). I am also editing the answer at the moment (I wanted to provide some basic information).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: This should be correct, I've tested it although I would not bet my life on it :D.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that an `uncle` is working (sort of) and the `aunt` does not because your definition of `male` and `female` is deficient: it does not recognize people a male or a female unless they have kids. In your set of facts there is no female (judging by name) who would have kids and have a sibling who has kids. It is for the same reason that `scott` should not be showing up among the list of uncles.

Fixing this is simple: you could either

1. drop the rules that infer gender and state the gender instead, or
2. replace the `parents` facts with `son`/`daughter` facts + `parents` rule, and infer the gender from the fact that someone is a daughter of someone.

Comment: Hmm, I understand your solution. As I already mentioned I was given all of the code by my lecturer and told to write an aunt, uncle & cousin rule. Is there any way of doing this with the rules / facts as they are? Or was I supplied with defective code from the start?

Comment: @DannyWalsh In order to know that someone is someone else's aunt you need to know that it's a female sibling of one of the parents, or a spouse of a male sibling of one of the parents.  Judging from the set that you presented, the only way to tell someone's gender is to wait for them to have a child, and  is to see on which side of the `parents` relationship they end up. I do not see how to fix this without introducing new facts. Here is a demo of the first approach ([link](http://ideone.com/zkkjIk)).

Answer (score 3):

You are asking why `aunt(A,P)` does not have any solution. In other words

> There are no aunts.

Here is a systematic way to localize the problem using program slicing. Since the program relevant for `aunt/2` is a pure monotonic program, we can localize the problem in a very systematic manner.

Your problem is this: you have a goal `aunt(A,P)` that is too specialized. We will now try to generalize it. But only as long as the goal still fails. In this manner we will obtain a maximal generalization that still fails. Therefore, the problem must be somewhere in the remaining part.

To begin with, let me introduce the following definition in your program:

```
:- op(950,fx, *).

*_.
```

This permits to "comment out" a goal with prefix `*`. In this manner we will generalize your program. Let us try this out with the definition of aunt. That is, insert `*` in front of a goal, reload the example and see if it still fails. The following is its maximal generalization:

```
aunt(X,Y) :- sister(X,Z), * parents(Y, Z, _).
aunt(X,Y) :- sister(X,Z), * parents(Y, _, Z).
```

Even that generalization fails! So, in other words, also `sister/2` is always failing.

> There are no sisters.

```
sister(X, Y) :- female(X), father(Z, X), * father(Z, Y).
```

And even above fails!

> There are no females with a father.

You might stick to this, or continue, by replacing the goals by their definitions.

```
sister(X, Y) :- mother(X,_), parents(X, Z, _), * father(Z, Y).
```

one more:

```
sister(X, Y) :- parents(_,_,X), parents(X, Z, _), * father(Z, Y).
```

So only mothers may be sisters which certainly is a bit too much of a restriction.